# What's a good name for the type Map<Id<T>, T>?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, flowtype

I'm working on adding Flow types to an existing code base, and there's a type I'm using fairly often: `Map<Id<Foo>, Foo>` (The `Id` type is an opaque type which is actually just a string, so that IDs for different types of objects have different types)

Is there a common or standard name for that type: a map whose values are a certain type of object and whose keys are the IDs of those objects? For example if you called it an `IdMap` then you'd write `type IdMap<T> = Map<Id<T>, T>;` since `IdMap<Foo>` is less cumbersome to write over and over.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it `Records<T>` because I think of things with IDs as "records".

> The `Id` type is an opaque type which is actually just a string, so that IDs for different types of objects have different types

I love this idea! I also think the shorter alias is a great idea!